# Actionscript 3.0 - Making a sprite move after it has collided with another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to code a movie clip object to move after it has been "hit" with another object. I can make it move like this:

```
if (bat.hitTestObject(ball)
{   
bat.x += xMovement;
}
```

This only makes it move by xMovement which in this case is 5 when it has hit but I would like it to continue to move afterwards. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To "keep moving" you need to increment over time, for example at each frame using `enterFrame` or at an arbitrary interval using a `Timer`.

For example:

```
if (bat.hitTestObject(ball)) {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBat);
}

function moveBat(e:Event):void {
    bat.x += xMovement;
}
```

To stop moving the bat at any point, remove the `enterFrame` handler:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBat);
```